VBA Find function with DateTime
I am having issues with a find function looking for cells with datetime format "yyyy-mm-ss h:mm"
The function below only seems to work when find cells with a timestamp of 0:00 (12 AM) and does not work for anything else (block variable error 91). I have tried using xlWhole, MATCH function, changing the formatting of the lookup table cells to "yyyy-mm-ss hh:mm:ss AM/PM" format to match what seems to be the output of CDate with no luck. Please... any advice would be helpful.
PasteLoc = YearSheet.Range("W:W").Find(CDate(CellTime), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart).Row


Excel stores time as a double. Then it "masks" that double to look like a date/time.  Trying to match on a double with up to 15 significant digits will be nearly impossible.  When you get down to the time part there are a large number of decimals that can represent the same minute.

May I ask what you get with Excel formula =Cell("format", a_cell_in_col_w) and =Cell("type", a_cell_in_col_w)? Also what sort of values are you trying to look up via CellTime?

The solution to find the specified timestamp is
Sub FindDateTime()
  Dim CellTime As Double, PasteLoc As Long, cc As Range, prec As Double
  CellTime = CDbl(CDate("22.08.2024  23:27:48"))
  prec = 1 / 24 / 3600
  For Each cc In Range("A1:A6")
    If Abs(CellTime - cc) < prec Then
      PasteLoc = cc.Row
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  Debug.Print PasteLoc ' 4
End Sub


It finds the timestamp with precision (prec) of 1 s.
Another approach can be using of the datetime text representation
Sub FindDateTimeAsText()
  Dim CellTime As String, PasteLoc As Long, cc As Range
  CellTime = "2024.08.22 23:27"
  For Each cc In Range("A1:A6")
    If CellTime = cc.Text Then
      PasteLoc = cc.Row
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  Debug.Print PasteLoc ' 4
End Sub

This solution is dependent of cell formats while the first one is not. The string representation of a timestamp should be in the same format with cells.

Good answer but it wasn't clear to me on first reading that A4 contains 22.08.2024  23:27:48 in both cases but in the second case would have to be formatted as yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss if you included seconds in CellTime. As it stands the second macro just matches on minutes ignoring seconds.

Sure, for text search, the string representation of a timestamp should be in the same format with cells. If the cell format is "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss", you need to search "2024.08.22 23:27:48".

A4 contains "22.08.2024 23:27:48", but cell is formatted as "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm". "cc.Text" supplies cell's value in the text representation exactly as it displayed, thus we need to search "2024.08.22 23:27".

A4 contains "22.08.2024 23:27:48" - here the timestamp is expressed in the human oriented form, but in Excel A4 contains 45526.97764. You can see this number applying the "General" format to the cell, it's available in VBA through the Value property. And, according to the associated format, Excel displays the timestamp in the text representation, which is available in VBA through the Text property.
